# How to partition drive in use? 16.04

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I need to partition the hard drive I have Ubuntu installed on. How can I do this without loosing data? Using Gparted it seems like I cannot do this without unmounting it.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/use-gparted-to-partition-hard-drive-2205693

Comment: Ubuntu partition needs to be unmounted to change it.  Can do with a live ubuntu USB(one you use to install with).

Comment: Think unmounting tends to protect data when changing partition size.

Comment: What is your intention? To change the SIZE of existing partitions, or to ADD parttitions? Show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: I'm installing windows on my PC, but would like to preserve my data without buying a secondary drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `in use` I am assuming the drive from which OS is booted. Just like you cannot change the tyre on a running car, you cannot do any partitioning on the drive from which your Linux is booted.

You must stop the car.

You may use live boot (the one you made during installing Ubuntu will work fine), or boot into another OS (in case of a dual boot).

You cannot really make any changes to the drive on which you Linux is booted from. However this can be done on Windows 10, but that is something not relevant here. Just mentioned it for knowledge.